# The argument type 'Widget Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String? Function(String?)?' In flutter

Tags: flutter, validation, dart

[customeradd.dart error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0XIv.png)   I tried to create |CustomerAdding`page layout that contains user inputs using`mixins`in`Flutter`.

I made a globalkey to validate the form.

and I had 4 `Textfield` methods as widgets represents `user inputs`, but when I try to call mixins my validator it gives red sign saying;

The argument type `Widget Function()` can't be assigned to the parameter type `String`?

"validation_mixin.dart" page below

```
     class ValidationMixin {
    
   String? validateFirstName(String value) {
     if (value.length < 2) {
       return "at least 2 characters please";
     }
   }

   String? validateLastName(String value) {
     if (value.length < 2) {
       return "at least 2 characters please";
     }
   }

   String? validateEmail(String value) {
     if (!value.contains("@")) {
       return "mail is not valid";
     }
   }
 }
```

customeradd.dart complete page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:forms_application_1/mixin/validation_mixin.dart';

class CustomerAdd extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => CustomerAddState();
}

class CustomerAddState extends State with ValidationMixin {
  // global form key for Form
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            //let's create user inputs with methods
            // These inputs include "name lastname email password"
            // I create these inputs as methods so that we could call them in column
            firstNameField(),
            lastNameField(),
            emailField(),
            passwordField(),
            submitButton()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // 4 Textfield methods down there as widgets;

  Widget firstNameField() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          // we use inputdecoration field for labeling input
          labelText: "name",
          hintText: "exp: Denis"),
      validator: validateFirstName,
    );
  }

  Widget lastNameField() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          // we use inputdecoration field for labeling input
          labelText: "Lastname",
          hintText: "surname"),
      validator: validateLastName,
    );
  }

  Widget emailField() {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      // we use inputdecoration field for labeling input
      decoration:
          InputDecoration(labelText: "Email", hintText: "exp: abc@mail.com"),
      validator: validateEmail,
    );
  }

  Widget passwordField() {
    return TextFormField(
      obscureText: true, // it hides the password field ****

      // we use inputdecoration field for labeling input
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "password", hintText: "password"),
    );
  }

// SAVE BUTTON CREATİON down there

  Widget submitButton() {
    return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false otherwise.

          if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
            // If the form is valid, display a snackbar. In the real world,
            // you'd often call a server or save the information in a database.

            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Processing 

Data')));
          }
        },
        child: Text("SAVE"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your validator methods?

Comment: I pasted complete page :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because the [validator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormField/validator.html) takes `String? Function(T? value)`. To fix this add the `?` in the parameter and check if the `value` is not null.

```
class ValidationMixin {
   String? validateFirstName(String? value) {
     if (value != null && value.length < 2) {
       return "at least 2 characters please";
     }
   }

   String? validateLastName(String? value) {
     if (value != null && value.length < 2) {
       return "at least 2 characters please";
     }
   }

   String? validateEmail(String? value) {
     if (value != null &&!value.contains("@")) {
       return "mail is not valid";
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: man you saved the day thank you so much :-). this null safety update that I still didnt catch up in flutter though

Answer (score 0):

I think Dart is confused with the function name and mixin name they are the same!

[image]

Please try below code :-

```
Widget firstNameField(){
 return TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
   labelText: "name",
   hintText: "exp: Denis"
  ),
  validator: validateFirstName,
 );
}
```

Comment: made a mistake  sorry I covered it up quickly it gives the error still I use flutter version 2.3.0 btw

Comment: OK, Fine @DenizKoc